# Can I execute functions within a contract (transact) from multiple accounts?

Tags: contract-invocation, truffle, testrpc

I have a contract that is deployed on the local test blockchain. I am using testrpc and truffle for testing my contract. However, I wish to execute functions of the contract from multiple accounts (2 at least). Is it possible using truffle console?

Comment: By default, it always uses account[0] but can I do the same from different account so that _**msg.sender**_ value will now have different account address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like mentionned in the doc :

```
var account_one = "0x1234..."; // an address
var account_two = "0xabcd..."; // another address

var meta;

MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;
  return meta.sendCoin(account_two, 10, {from: account_one});
}).then(function(result) {
  // If this callback is called, the transaction was successfully processed.
  alert("Transaction successful!")
}).catch(function(e) {
  // There was an error! Handle it.
})
```

just creat two variables each contain an account address and then send differents transactions.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention here. I did look at the truffle doc and saw this example before your post. Not sure how I missed it. Thanks a lot man!