# What is the {from: account_one} third parameter in metacoin.js test example

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract

When working through the MetaCoin sample project; within the MetaCoin.sol file we have this method:

```
function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    return true;
}
```

Inside the test script; when calling the `sendCoin` method; the code is passing a third parameter: `{from: account_one}`

```
return meta.sendCoin(account_two, amount, {from: account_one});
```

I can understand the code needs to know from *what* account to send the coin from; but I am not understanding how this is working as the `sendCoin` method signature has two parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in truffle you always need to add this object parameter representing the values you need for transactions in Ethereum.
like in:

`eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x036a03fc47084741f83938296a1c8ef67f6e34fa', to: '0xa8ade7feab1ece71446bed25fa0cf6745c19c3d5', value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})`

the `to` is provided by Truffle, which is of course the contract's address. But things like `from`, `gas` and `value` can/should/must be defined by hand. So the last arg is an object containing these parameters.
Hint: When simply calling (read-only) a function, you can provide the `from` information, too, to pass a specific wallet address to a contract and get desired information returned.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet of contract code you're looking at uses `msg.sender`, which is a [special variable](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=msg.sender#special-variables-and-functions) that always exists in the global namespace.

Normally when you call a contract, the `msg.sender` value will reflect the address of the default account of the caller (i.e. `account[0]`).

If you don't want to use the default account, then you can explicitly specify a different account using the `{from: <a_different_account>}` method. In your case the `account_one` variable can be set to point to any address you own.

**Edit:**

Also see this previous thread: [Can I execute functions within a contract (transact) from multiple accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/can-i-execute-functions-within-a-contract-transact-from-multiple-accounts/13545#13545)

Answer (score 0):

https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/how-to/contracts/interact-with-your-contracts/ says:

> We passed an object as the third parameter to sendCoin. Note that the sendCoin function in our Solidity contract doesn't have a third parameter. What you see above is a special object that can always be passed as the last parameter to a function that lets you edit specific details about the transaction ("transaction params"). Here, we set the from address ensuring this transaction came from accounts[0]. The transaction params that you can set correspond to the fields in an Ethereum transaction:

> - from
> - to
> - gas
> - gasPrice
> - value
> - data
> - nonce

It is optional and as Richard Horrocks said, `from` defaults to `accounts[0]`.  I guess that default is in the same way that the initial gas to migrate the contract comes from the same account.